# Resizing Ubuntu partitions (root and home) safely in a dual booted system

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

My laptop has dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04). When I was installing Ubuntu, I gave 25 GB of space to my root partition and 100 GB to my home partition. I had no idea that every program that I would later install in Ubuntu would go to the root partition. Every dual boot tutorial I read said that 20 GB for the root was a good size and that I should allocate more space to the home partition. So I did, thinking the root partition would only contain the OS and nothing more (programs would be installed in home)... But I already have 15 GB used because I installed a large program and there are a couple I need to install yet.
So, is there a safe way to resize my Ubuntu (only Ubuntu!) partitions without affecting Windows?

Comment: I'd suggest booting your Ubuntu install media; and use `gparted` to adjust the sizes of partitions. You can't do easily if you use your running Ubuntu, as the partition will be being used (thus mounted, it needs to be unmounted).  You may need to correct grub if you 'move' the stage1.5 (/boot/ part of your drive; but this can be fixed if necessary (it may not require fix if you even use grub; so try first)  fyi:  even Ubuntu's site recommends 30gb : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes as release-upgrading to the next version needs lots of space so 32gb+ is usually recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guiverc has explained in the comments how to allocate space to your `root` partition.  I'll address the part of your question/confusion about space used.

**Where files are stored / System usage**

20 gigs is fine for running Ubuntu and using the programs (the elaborate suite) that are already.  That includes much of what many people use the computer for, browsing the Internet (Chromium/Firefox), Writing documents, mail merge and other word processing activities (Libre Office).  I can go on with a very long list, which includes 10's of applications and thousands of commands tools.

You can't install many other programs with only 20 or 25 gigs.

All the programs that you install will go into the `root` partition, not your home partition.  Your home partition is where your personal configuration from the programs, as well as the data, such as your documents, pictures, videos, and movies and such.  The `root` partition may not change very much once you have your choice of applications installed.  But the personal data doesn't stop growing.

**A safe way to resize**

As long as you don't touch your Windows partition, it won't be affected.  You can use the `gparted` disk management tool to resize your Ubuntu fairly seamlessly.  It's included in your Ubuntu installation disk.  Use the **Try Ubuntu** option to work from there.

You can easily identify your Ubuntu partitions both by the **size** that you already know they are and the format type which is **ext4**.  You can identify your Windows partition by the format type which is **ntfs**.

Use the disk manager **Gparted** to adjust your home and root partitions with the GUI sliders.  Then just save the changes.

I've never experienced boot problems with resizing the partitions.  But if for some reason, it doesn't boot, reinstalling **Grub** would fix that.  A Grub install will automatically detect the installed operating systems (Windows and Linux) and add them to the boot menu.

Since the Windows partition will be untouched, Windows boot could be fixed by running a Windows recovery disk to fix the windows boot.

**Note:**

Installing or Reinstalling Ubuntu is a very seamless way of recovering from a boot corruption.  The new install will ask you to point to the partition where you want Ubuntu installed.  As long as you don't mark format the partition, it'll remove only the Ubuntu files and replace them with the fresh install.  It won't touch your `/home` or `Windows` partition.  Both your `/home` and `Windows` partition basically safe when your work on the partitions by specific name.